# Limit of a Function that is the Product of two Functions.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, proof-verification

I am trying to show the following,

> Let $f : \mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function such that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$$
>
> Let $g : \mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function such that $$g(x) = f(x)\left[1+\text{sin}\left(2 \pi \text{ln}(x)\right)\right]$$
>
> Show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 0$.

My attempt:

We know $g(x) = f(x)\left[1+\text{sin}\left(2 \pi \text{ln}(x)\right)\right]$ and $$ 0 \leq \left[1+\text{sin}\left(2 \pi \text{ln}(x)\right)\right] \leq 2$$

Hence, $$\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$$
and $$\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$$

Is this correct / rigorous enough? Is there a better way of doing this? I am not sure that the fact that $1 + \text{sin}(2 \pi \text{ln}(x))$ is bounded is enough, since some limits don't converge due to rapid oscillation. How can I make my attempt better?

Does this principle apply in general when we have some limiting behaviour of a function $f$, and a bounded function $g$, is the limiting behaviour of $fg$ the same as that of $f$?

Comment: This is correct, although I would highlight that $g$ is the product of $f$ by something that is bounded.

Comment: You can make more explicit what you are using. For example, the inequalities that you wrote imply $0\leq |g(x)|=|f(x)||1+\sin(2\pi\ln(x))|\leq 2|f(x)|$. Then, by the [whichever-way-you-call-it theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), the limit of $|g(x)|$ is zero. This implies that the limit of $g(x)$ is also zero.

Comment: $g(x) = f(x)h(x).$ If $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x), \lim_\limits{x\to a} h(x)$ exist  $\lim_\limits{x\to a} g(x)  = (\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x) )(\lim_\limits{x\to a} h(x)), h(x)$ is bounded.  i.e. $0\le h(x)\le 2, 0<\lim_\limits{x\to a} g(x) <2\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clarify the use of the squeeze theorem: since $0\le 1+\sin(2\pi\ln x)\le 2$, we also have
$$
0\le g(x)\le 2f(x)
$$
and since $\lim_{x\to?}f(x)=0$ (where $?=\infty$ or $?=0^+$), we can conclude that
$$
\lim_{x\to?}g(x)=0
$$

This uses *substantially* that the limits of $f$ are both zero, otherwise the application of the squeeze theorem cannot be done. A simple example: $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=f(x)(1+\sin(2\pi\ln x))$. Neither the limit at $0^+$ nor the limit at $\infty$ exist.